# Pl/Sql Open Cursor inside for loop

Tags: oracle, plsql

i'm creating a stored procedure in Oracle Pl/Sql, first i have to create a bidimensional array with the IDs of the records that match a certain criteria, i already do that, next i have to query through a specific table and get the data of the IDs of my "final array".

This is the part of the SP where i loop through the final array and query the table.

```
FOR x IN array_final.FIRST .. array_final.LAST

LOOP
   OPEN voCursor FOR
   SELECT ID AS IDTRX FROM TBL_TRANSACTION WHERE ID in (array_final(x)(1));
   dbms_output.Put_line(x);
   totReg := x;


END LOOP;
```

the thing is, the cursor is only getting the last record.

This is the Java code where i get the results from the resulset.

[image]

and this is what the console is displaying, it says 2 records but only one ID is displayed, the last one

[image]

How could i have the 2 records into the cursor inside the for loop?? is there a better way to accomplish this?

Any help is welcome, Greetings

Comment: It doesn't make sense to open a cursor in a loop and not do anything with it.  Each time you open the cursor, you're discarding the prior query.  Assuming `voCursor` is an `out` parameter in the procedure, the caller would only be able to fetch the data from the last query that was used to open the cursor.  I'm guessing that is what you're seeing assuming that `totReg` in your Java code is somehow getting populated from the `totReg` in the PL/SQL code.

Comment: voCursor is an out parameter, that's exactly the issue i'm facing, i need all the data in the cursor, how could i do that?

Comment: How is `array_final` declared?  Is it a SQL type or a PL/SQL type?  How is it populated?  The simplest option would be to take whatever query populates that collection and combine that with the `SELECT` statement rather than populating the collection in one step and using it in a query in a subsequent step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why cursor? I'd declare a variable

```
l_idtrx remove.id%type;
```

remove

```
OPEN voCursor FOR
```

and just

```
SELECT ID into l_idtrx FROM remove ...
```

---

**[EDIT: refcursor it is]**

Here's a quick example of how you might be doing it. As you already have most of it done, apply pieces you're missing.

```
SQL> create or replace function f_test
  2    return sys_refcursor
  3  is
  4    l_rc  sys_refcursor;
  5    l_arr sys.odcinumberlist := sys.odcinumberlist(10, 20, 30);
  6  begin
  7    open l_rc for
  8      select deptno, dname, loc
  9      from dept join table(l_arr) on deptno = column_value;
 10    return l_rc;
 11  end;
 12  /

Function created.

SQL> select f_test from dual;

F_TEST
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

    DEPTNO DNAME          LOC
---------- -------------- -------------
        10 ACCOUNTING     NEW YORK
        20 RESEARCH       DALLAS
        30 SALES          CHICAGO


SQL>
```

Comment: i'll try, but one question, it's a requirement to have a cursor as an OUT parameter, is there a way to do it with a cursor??

Comment: That would be a **refcursor**, not *cursor*, I presume.

Comment: the voCursor is a  refCursor type

Comment: Just like I said. I added some more code to my answer; have a look, please.

Comment: thanks man, it helped me a lot, what i did was to create a type of numeric array with the ids so i didn't have to loop, and in the select i use "where id in (select id from table(array_ids))"